# Python Random Seat Generator with Memory

Tags: python, excel, random

So i've done some searching around for similar projects to this and haven't come across anything that has pushed me in the right direction yet as to how to tackle this project so I'm coming here to Stack to get some advice. I am not necessarily looking for the full solution to this project, as I would like to tackle it myself, just simply looking for some advice on how to approach it.

**What I'm trying to do**

I am trying to write a program to randomly generate seating charts for eight weeks of a class. It reads a list of 80 names from an excel file and spits out another excel file, within this output file are 8 worksheets, one for each week, each with a different randomly generated 8x10 seating chart. Easy right?

There are three additional criteria that I would like to achieve that make this a bit more perplexing:

- I would like avoid having any one student sit next to (in front of, behind, or to the side of) the same student for any two weeks
- I would not like to have any one student sit in the front or back rows for more than one week as well
- These students live in dormitories together, and I would like to not have any students from the same room sitting next to one another during any week

This is for an 8 week MBA class and the whole reason why I am trying to do this is to introduce the students to new peers and spark up new conversations.

**What I've done so far**

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
import random
import itertools


load_wb = raw_input('What is the name of the file containing your students?\n')
num_of_weeks = int(raw_input('How many weeks would you like?\n'))


dest_filename = 'seating_chart.xlsx'
students = []


load_wb = load_workbook(load_wb).active

for cell in load_wb.iter_rows():
  students.append(cell[0].value)


def make_grid():
  #Make the 8 x 10 grid
  y_list = list(range(1, 11))
  x_list = list(range(1, 9))
  grid = []

  for y in y_list:
    for x in x_list:
      grid.append((x,y))

  return grid



save_wb = Workbook()
grid = make_grid()
for week in range(num_of_weeks):
  week +=1 
  if week == 1:
    ws = save_wb.active
  else:
    ws = save_wb.create_sheet()
  ws.title = 'Week '+str(week)

  #Randomly shuffle the students array
  random.shuffle(students)
  for x, student in itertools.izip(grid, students):
    x,y = x
    ws.cell(row=x, column=y, value=student)


save_wb.save(filename=dest_filename)
```

I know that I am obviously going to have to store the values of where each student is sitting each week and reference these when generating the random charts but I am relatively new to Python and not sure how to best approach this.

I appreciate everyone's advice in advance! :)

Joey

Comment: There are two sides to this, I think. The software design and the algorithm. I *think* the latter is some sort of coloring problem that could be best discussed on Math SE.

Comment: You might be able to get away with randomly generating seating arrangements and checking for your criteria. As to reading and writing Excel worksheets, I don't have any experience with openpyxl. If you have any problems with it, you  can do what I always do: export to a csv file and then write csv files and import those into Excel.

Comment: Also, this is not exactly the kind of question Stack Overflow expects. You can have more luck if you come up with separate more specific questions while keeping them general enough; like how to generate seating arrangements with certain criteria, or how to read/write excel documents in Python, etc.

Comment: The excel file is not a must, I am already capable of reading/writing to the Excel files, that is quite easy. I can even get away with a csv file if that makes things easier, I'm more so interested in achieving the three criteria for the seating arrangements. Thanks for your input guys!

Comment: How many students to a dorm room?

Comment: @Eric, 8 people to a living group

Comment: @JoeyOrlando: Always 10 groups of 8, or (k>=10) groups of (n <= 8) students?

Comment: @Eric the dorm groups will never be more than 8, but it is possible that there will be instances where there are less than 80 students and one dorm group may have <8 students in it

Answer (score 0):

Here's one method:

1. Divide the class into two groups, such that no one in group A lives in the same room as group B (possible if all dorm groups are 8 people, otherwise still nearly possible)
2. Arrange group A in into a checkerboard pattern, and have them keep their seats throughout
3. Arrange group B into a checkboard pattern, sitting around A. Each lesson, move group B 3 seats in the short dimension and one seat in the long dimension. Wrap around both ways like a torus. You get exactly 8 goes here before a repeat seat, which is convenient